# How to reverse a number with 0 in the 1's place?

Tags: java, int, reverse

I have this so far:

```
    int n = 6718390
    int rev = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        rev = rev*10 + n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }
```

and I get n = 938176. I've tried looking all around and can't find an answer. A lot of people talk about this special case but no luck on a solution. I'd really prefer not to use strings or arrays. Thanks!

Comment: ~ is the binary negation, altough you have to acount for positive and negative numbers, I don't know whether the sign is switched aswell.

Comment: There is no such thing as an `int` with a leading `0`.

Comment: What number (not a string) *do* you expect it to reverse to?

Comment: Do you expect "0938176"?

Comment: Leading zeros in java numbers are automatically removed. If you want a leading zero on any number, you need to convert it to a string then concatenate that with the zero

Comment: I was expecting 0938176. Thank you for the help. Looks like I will have to convert it to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to have an int with a leading zero. It is automatically removed. You have to use something else. I'll just leave you with a really fast String method even if you don't use it it's good to at least know it exists.

```
public String reverse(String s){

    return new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString();

}
```